# Función JS retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando iterar un array para obtener una propiedad que contiene y la función de js me devuelve undefined.

La función es:

```
function returnThumbnail(value) {
return value.forEach(element => {
    element.url;
    
});
```

}
Y la llamada la hago desde aquí:

```
<div>${returnThumbnail(value)}</div>
```

Value es un array formado por los siguientes elementos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En definitiva quiero obtener el valor de la variable url y mostrarlo en una etiqueta div. Ahora mismo me muestra undefined.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué acción tiene que hacer con el valor `element.url`? El código no es incorrecto, pero no parece que devuelva nada. Prueba poner `console.log(element.url)` en donde ahora tienes `element.url` y verás que efectivamente sí recupera el valor, pero en la función no defines qué hacer con ello.

Comment: Tienes varias cosas mal en el código: 1.  `forEach` siempre devuelve `undefined`, quizá estás buscando la funcionalidad de `map`. 2. La función que le pasas a forEach, tampoco devuelve nada. 3. En el mejor de los casos, te devolvería un array de urls, no sólo una

Comment: Buenos días, quiero que ese valor que se devuelva se renderice dentro de una etiqueta img. Gracias

Comment: tienes que usar [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) si quieres obtener un array con las urls

Comment: @user1798310 ¿la pregunta entonces es cómo generar una colección de elementos `img` a partir de un array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es devolver el un array con la url de cada elemento, entonces debes hacerlo así:

```
function returnThumbnail(value) {
  return value.map(element => element.url);
};
```

Comment: Funciono a la perfección. muchas gracias